# I pulled my toddler in a wagon almost all day yesterday

Tags: muscle

My ribs on both sides hurt extremely bad when I move. However, if I'm resting they don't hurt. Is it possible I pulled some kind of muscle?

Comment: This question might be more-appropriate in health.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, because we can't diagnose pains over the internet, and two sentences of information wouldn't be enough even if we could.

Comment: @CCCV Health would close it for same reason-no interweb diagnosing.

Comment: That makes sense, @JohnP.

Comment: It's probably cancer, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed possible that you pulled a muscle. But, since the discomfort seems to be mostly symmetrical and less apparent while you rest, it seems more likely that you are experiencing Delayed-Onset Muscle Soreness.

If that's true, then your discomfort may peak about 48 hours after the initial stressor (pulling the wagon).

Consult a health professional if the discomfort persists more than a week later.